# Custom Layout With Android ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I thought what I wanted would be pretty simple, but there must be something I'm missing...

I setup a ViewPager with no problems.  It horizontally slides between different fragments.  However, when I try to add a header (or anything else) to my layout it force closes.  How do I do this?

Here is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_light"
    android:padding="0dp">

<!-- ***** HEADER ***** -->

    <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_dark"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_contentDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- ***** SLIDER ***** -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_pager_view">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my logcat:

```
03-28 19:31:30.447: D/dalvikvm(1023): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 3% free 9068K/9347K, paused 74ms
03-28 19:31:30.646: I/dalvikvm-heap(1023): Grow heap (frag case) to 25.721MB for 17613052-byte allocation
03-28 19:31:30.844: D/dalvikvm(1023): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 26267K/26567K, paused 20ms+19ms
03-28 19:31:33.524: D/dalvikvm(1023): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 26267K/26567K, paused 45ms
03-28 19:31:33.524: I/dalvikvm-heap(1023): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 39642008-byte allocation
03-28 19:31:33.604: D/dalvikvm(1023): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 2% free 26258K/26567K, paused 81ms
03-28 19:31:33.604: E/dalvikvm-heap(1023): Out of memory on a 39642008-byte allocation.
03-28 19:31:33.614: I/dalvikvm(1023): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
03-28 19:31:33.614: I/dalvikvm(1023):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x409c1460 self=0x12810
03-28 19:31:33.614: I/dalvikvm(1023):   | sysTid=1023 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074082952
03-28 19:31:33.614: I/dalvikvm(1023):   | schedstat=( 3201691068 885739274 101 ) utm=284 stm=36 core=0
03-28 19:31:33.614: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
03-28 19:31:33.624: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
03-28 19:31:33.634: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
03-28 19:31:33.634: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.634: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-28 19:31:33.634: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
03-28 19:31:33.634: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-28 19:31:33.634: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at com.mojackllc.postr.MainPagerActivity.onCreate(MainPagerActivity.java:20)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-28 19:31:33.645: I/dalvikvm(1023):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.654: D/AndroidRuntime(1023): Shutting down VM
03-28 19:31:33.654: W/dalvikvm(1023): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mojackllc.postr/com.mojackllc.postr.MainPagerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.mojackllc.postr.MainPagerActivity.onCreate(MainPagerActivity.java:20)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     ... 11 more
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     ... 23 more
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
03-28 19:31:33.754: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat error you are receiving? Also, you should be using dp or dip when providing layout sizes. SP should be used when specifying font sizes.

Comment: Logcat posted! I'm also changing sp -> dp.

Comment: You missed one :P you don't need to specify a value if you just want the value to be 0dip. Ex. android:padding="0dp" if you want it to be 0 just don't include the android:padding attribute to that element at all. Setting it to 0 is perfectly fine. But just not having it at all reduces code and cleans things up a bit. Just a tip that might be useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your image is gigantic:

> Out of memory on a 39642008-byte allocation.

That's 37.8MB. You're running out of memory.

Comment: Sounds right to me. Check the drawable "background_dark" and make sure that's not the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, you might actually want to check through all your drawables really. This is not small either: `Grow heap (frag case) to 25.721MB for 17613052-byte allocation`

Comment: Thanks!!! I accidentally saved hi-res images in my "drawable" folder.  Also, I had to change my LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and positioned "PageTitleStrip" below the header.